# How Do I Get The Scale of The Secondary Axis to be Based on My Series Values?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, charts, scale, axis

I'm using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization`. Charting to create charts in MVC.

I have a chart displaying values in a StackedColumn100 `SeriesChartType` with the corresponding y-axis values on the primary y-axis on the left side.

Since it is a 100% stacked column series, the primary y-axis is scaled from 0 to 100.

I have then added a secondary series in the form of a Line `SeriesChartType` tied to a secondary axis (on the right side). I would like this axis to adjust its scale based on the values in the series but it doesn't. No matter what the highest value of this series is, the secondary y-axis also has a scale between 0 to 100.

If I manually set the maximum value for the secondary y-axis the following way: 
`chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = 20;`. It works but I don't want to do that since the maximum value can differ greatly based on the search criteria used.

I have really tried to find a solution for this but I can't. According to the documentation and samples it seems that the scale should be based on the series values but I don't get it to work that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is a stand alone test function that recreates the problem. I call the function from my view with the following line:

```
<p><img src="@Url.Action("CreateChart_TestSecondaryAxis")" /> </p>

public FileResult CreateChart_TestSecondaryAxis()
        {
            System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            chart.Width = 800;
            chart.Height = 400;
            chart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240);
            chart.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
            chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
            chart.BorderlineWidth = 1;
            chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
            chart.BorderlineColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
            chart.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;
            chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
            chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
            chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal;

            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chartArea.Name = "TestSecondaryAxis";
            chartArea.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartArea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            chartArea.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font =
               new Font("Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                        8F, FontStyle.Regular);
            chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font =
               new Font("Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                        8F, FontStyle.Regular);
            chartArea.AxisY.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
            chartArea.AxisX.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
            chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);
            chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64, 64);

            chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Airport";
            chartArea.AxisY.Title = "LandingConf";
            chartArea.AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Rotated270;
            chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            Series seriesPrimaryAxisConf3 = new Series();
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.Name = "Conf 3";
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.Color = Color.Blue;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.BorderWidth = 2;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.ChartArea = "TestSecondaryAxis";
            DataPoint point;


            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                point = new DataPoint();
                point.AxisLabel = "Airport" + i.ToString();
                point.YValues = new double[] { i };

                seriesPrimaryAxisConf3.Points.Add(point);
            }

            chart.Series.Add(seriesPrimaryAxisConf3);

            Series seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull = new Series();
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.Name = "Conf Full";
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.Color = Color.Red;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.BorderWidth = 2;
            seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.ChartArea = "TestSecondaryAxis";


            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                point = new DataPoint();
                point.AxisLabel = "Airport" + i.ToString();
                point.YValues = new double[] { 11-i };

                seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull.Points.Add(point);
            }

            chart.Series.Add(seriesPrimaryAxisConfFull);

            Series seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights = new Series();
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.Name = "NoOfFLights";
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.Color = Color.Red;
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.BorderWidth = 2;
            seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.ChartArea = "TestSecondaryAxis";


            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                point = new DataPoint();
                point.AxisLabel = "Airport" + i.ToString();
                point.YValues = new double[] { i };

                seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights.Points.Add(point);
            }

            chart.Series.Add(seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights);
            chart.Series["NoOfFLights"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
            chart.ChartAreas["TestSecondaryAxis"].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chart.ChartAreas["TestSecondaryAxis"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart.ChartAreas["TestSecondaryAxis"].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            chart.SaveImage(ms);
            return File(ms.GetBuffer(), @"image/png");
        }
```

Comment: Try: `yourSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;`

Comment: Thank you for your input! I already do that though.

Comment: I create a chart, add the series to be plotted against the primary axis. Then I create the series to be plotted against the secondary axis and thereafter do the following: chart.Series["Nbr of flights"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;

Comment: I get the secondary axis and the series plotted against that axis is shown correctly, it is just that I would like the scale of the secondary axis to adjust to the values in the series displayed against it. Now it always goes from 0 to 100 just like the primary axis.

Comment: Is `"Nbr of flights"`  the name of the second series??

Comment: Yes, that is the name of the second series.

Comment: That would be strange. Here the axis show the scale of the series that is associated with it. Make sure to associate only one series with the secondary axis! Can you post an image?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Now I have finally created a test function that can be run stand alone that reproduces the problem. Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: Is there anyone out there who has managed to use a StackedColumn100 series chart type and get the scale of the secondary axis to adjust after the data in that series instead of using the same scale as the primary axis? I really cannot manage to get it to work. The above example reproduces the problem. I would be so grateful for any help!!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I never quite realized the strange issues that come with a Stacked100 type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSChart is a nice control but unfortunately **Microsoft has always failed** to properly **document** it.

And with the latest changes at MSDN things have gone **from bad to worse**, so I can't actually point to the rules that go for the various `ChartTypes`.

In your case I deduct this (rather wacky) rule:

> To attach a non 100%-series to an indepently scaled secondary y-axis
>   it must be the first series but the stacked series still must be added
>   first.

So, if you want to get a result like this:

[image]

..you need to adapt the code. Here are the changes and additions needed..:

First we have to **insert** the line series **at the front** but do that **after** the stack100 series have beeen added..:

```
chart.Series.Insert(0, seriesSecondaryAxisNoOfFlights);  // instead of adding it
```

Next we need to **owner-draw** the line as it would get **burried** under the columns otherwise.

Code the `PostPaint` event like this:

```
private void Chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Chart chart = sender as Chart;  //*
    Series s = chart.Series[0];  // make sure to pick the right one!

    Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2;  // !!

    var pts = s.Points.Select(x => 
        new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                   (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0])));

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(s.Color, s.BorderWidth))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, pts.ToArray());
}
```

For this to work the series need **valid** x-values. So add this line:

```
point.XValue = i;  // set both x and y-values!
```

I also added a few nudges to the axis positioning:

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas["TestSecondaryAxis"];
ca.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0.5;
ca.AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0.5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I would never have figured that out myself.

Comment: I don't really understand how the event works though. It doesn't know of the chart variable the the CreateChart_TestSecondaryAxis function created. Shall I pass the chart object to the event function somehow or what do I need to do for it to access the chart that was created in the test function?

Comment: I have updated (*) the answer to include referencing the chart.

Comment: It works like a charm! I can't thank you enough. You are my hero!